# Converting EPS to Tif Imagemagick with correct sizes

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a lots of EPS image with variable sizes, some are very small and some are large. When i open EPS image in Photoshop it can be resize to any bigger size without actually decreasing the quality. 
I have no problem converting EPS to TIFF, I even don't have resize problem if source EPS image is bigger in size, but when it comes to converting small EPS file, the converted TIFF doesnt look good.

Is there any way to resize the source EPS on the go so that quality is not lost and then convert it to TIFF file?
Here is the code i have got

```
exec(_IMPath_.$srcimagepath." -colorspace cmyk -compress none -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 -quality 100 ".$cmykpath);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for rasterizing the .eps file needs to be before the filename to have an effect. something like this should work...

```php
exec(_IMPath_." -density 300 ".$srcimagepath." -colorspace cmyk -compress none -units PixelsPerInch -quality 100 ".$cmykpath);
```

equivalent to the command...

```
convert -density 300 filename.eps -colorspace cmyk -compress none -units PixelsPerInch -quality 100 filename.tif
```

you might also want to add a resize parameter e.g. `-resize 4096x4096`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, asked some 9 years ago, hopefully this will help someone else. :)

Comment: That's the idea.